# Disk doesn't boot with firmware pass enabled (High Sierra)

Tags: mac, firmware

I'm trying to enable firmware password protection on my Mac. According to [HT204455](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455) I can accomplish this by booting into Recovery Mode, enabling the Firmware password there, and then reboot normally.

But if I do this, the internal disk will no longer boot normally. It just shows a question mark as if there's no disk attached (I can still boot to recovery mode, single user etc but wont go to regular login screen).

How can I fix this to enable use of firmware password?

Comment: As said before, the question is unclear. What are you trying to accomplish (what is the expected target state), where are you starting from, what have you tried and how does it fail?. Which instructions are you following? Do you have FileVault enabled on the disk?

Comment: I've now edited the question into what I understand to be the question. Feel free to fix/add anything I've missed.

Comment: No one has any suggestions?